# Converting Java loop to C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

how should I convert Java loop code to C#?

Java:

```
for (int i = 0; i < edges[index].length; i++) {
    edges[index][i] = 0;
    edges[i][index] = 0;    
}
```

I'm stuck with the `edges[index].length` part, is there any similar method in C#?

For reference, `edges` is `int[,]` array, `index` is some integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using GetLength?

edges.GetLength(index);

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In C#, Properties and Methods should start with an uppercased letter. Try `Length` instead of `length`